# Memory PerformanceCounter C#

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I'm having trouble with a PerformanceCounter in C#. When I run it against remote machines it runs fine, but when trying to run it against the machine it is running on I get the following Error: **System.InvalidOperationException: 'Could not locate Performance Counter with specified category name 'Memory', counter name '% Committed Bytes In Use'.'**

```
            int i = 1;
            PerformanceCounter ramPerfCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
            ramPerfCounter.CategoryName = "Memory";
            ramPerfCounter.CounterName = "% Committed Bytes In Use";
            ramPerfCounter.MachineName = "server";
            ramPerfCounter.ReadOnly = true;

            PerformanceCounter cpuPerfCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
            cpuPerfCounter.CategoryName = "Processor";
            cpuPerfCounter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
            cpuPerfCounter.InstanceName = "_Total";
            cpuPerfCounter.MachineName = "server";
            cpuPerfCounter.ReadOnly = true;

            do
            {

                float fMemory = ramPerfCounter.NextValue();
                float fCpu = cpuPerfCounter.NextValue();

                Console.WriteLine("CPU: " + fCpu.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("RAM:" + fMemory.ToString());
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            while (i == 1);
```

The CPU performance counter works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a couple of issues

1. You don't need to specify MachineName for running on a local instance, this is used to connect to a read-only remote instance.
2. The counter name could be localised on your local machine

To check if the counter is available on your machine

1. Go to "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools" in explorer
2. Open Performance Monitor
3. On the Monitoring Tools -> Performance Monitor panel, click the + button to add a new counter
4. Click select Memory from the list and see the available counters.

Alternatively you could use this code to get a list of categories

```
public static List<string> GetCategoryNames(string machineName)
{
    List<string> catNameList = new List<string>();
    List<PerformanceCounterCategory> categories = new List<PerformanceCounterCategory>();
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(machineName))
        {
            categories = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories(machineName).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            categories = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories().ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    foreach(PerformanceCounterCategory category in categories)
    {
        catNameList.Add(category.CategoryName);
    }
    catNameList.Sort();
    return catNameList;
}
```

Then add a catNameList.Contains() call to check if the counter is available.

To find all the counters you could use

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetPerfCounterNames(string machineName)
{
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> perfCounterList = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    List<PerformanceCounterCategory> categories = new List<PerformanceCounterCategory>();
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(machineName))
        {
            categories = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories(machineName).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            categories = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories().ToList();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    foreach (PerformanceCounterCategory category in categories)
    {
        List<PerformanceCounter> pcList = null;
        if (category.GetInstanceNames().Length > 0)
        {
            pcList = category.GetCounters(category.GetInstanceNames()[0]).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            pcList = category.GetCounters().ToList();
        }
        List<string> pcNameList = new List<string>();
        foreach (PerformanceCounter pc in pcList)
        {
            pcNameList.Add(pc.CounterName);
        }
        pcNameList.Sort();
        perfCounterList.Add(category.CategoryName, pcNameList);
    }
    return perfCounterList;
}
```

Comment: I've tried not adding a machine name, and I checked in Perfmon, the listed category and counter are the same as in my code.

Comment: Could be obvious, but are you running with admin rights on the local machine?

Comment: The category name does exist, but it looks like the counters that Memory is returning are from some other category. I am running as local admin. https://imgur.com/a/eYEXgJ7

Comment: Interesting, that's a bit of gold knowledge, which category is to coming from on your localhost?

Comment: Here is an example of some counters it's returning, they don't even seem to be associated with the Memory category... https://imgur.com/a/eYEXgJ7

Comment: Very strange, you could try to rebuild the pc counters check out "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/manually-rebuild-performance-counters"

Comment: That is still returning the wrong counter names on a local PC, but not on my remote server. Have you tried running that against your local PC to see if you have "% Committed Bytes In Use" available to you?

Comment: Its fine for me on my localmachine, "Memory" -> "% Committed Bytes In Use" exists